# Why the elements in the array are always zero?

Tags: java, arrays

I have to code a method called productOfPrevious that takes an array of integers and returns an array of integers of the same size as the input. Each cell in the returned array is the product of the cell by all the previous cells.

```
    void l3() {
            int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
            int[] retArr = productPrevious(arr);

            for (int elem: retArr){
                System.out.print(elem + " ");
            }
        }

        public int[] productPrevious (int[] arr){
            int[] retArr = new int[arr.length];
            int product = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                product = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
                    product *= arr[j];
                }
                retArr[i] = product;
            }
            return retArr;
        }
```

And this is my code. But I don't know why the elements in the output array are always zero.

Input: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Output that I want: {1, 2, 6, 24, 120}

The output I'm getting: {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Is anything wrong with my code?

Comment: because product is zero and due to that `product *= arr[j];` will be zero. Assign it 1.

Comment: Since you start with each iteration of the loop with 'product = 0;', when you multiply the numbers from the array, you always get 0.  Try 'product = 1;'

Comment: Hint: if you do not understand what your code is doing: pick a piece of paper and a pen, and run the code yourself, with a small example at least. Or: learn to use a debugger. Or: simply add print statements. You see: learning programming is only 10% about writing down lines of code. The rest is figuring out WHY the things you wrote down give you unexpected results. So, consider asking others your LAST resort. First use the 3 methods I mentioned above extensively.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2):

Because of your *product* variable is 0 by default.

**0 * (any other number) = 0**

Set your *product* variable to 1 to fix problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning  `product = 0` and product of 0 is always `0`

initialize product to `1` will work fine like below

```
public static int[] productPrevious (int[] arr){
        int[] retArr = new int[arr.length];
        int product = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            product = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
                product *= arr[j];
                System.out.println(product);
            }
            retArr[i] = product;
        }
        return retArr;
    }
```